# What are some non-elementary integrals that are solvable without complex analysis?

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm relatively new to non-elementary integrals, and have only done two, the Gaussian and Dirichlet. Also no Fourier or Laplace, as I have not studied those yet. I know I probably should study more before attempting such integrals, and most answers will probably tell me to do so, but I haven't a lot of time. Anything with the Feynman trick perhaps? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hardy 'The integral $\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{\sin x}{x} \, dx$', [*Mathematical Gazette* Vol. 5, No. 80](http://people.math.harvard.edu/~ctm/home/text/others/hardy/sinx/sinx.pdf) (1909), pp. 98–103, a paper that considers a number of ways of evaluating said integral, also gives the following as examples of "properly definite" integrals (i.e. those which cannot be evaluated using an elementary antiderivative):

> [...] certain cases in which the integral can be calculated directly from its definition as a sum, as can the integrals
>   $$ \int_0^{\pi/2} \log \sin \theta \, d\theta , \qquad \int_0^{\pi/2} \log(1-2p\cos \theta + p^2) \, d\theta .  $$

i.e., for example, by computing
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \log \sin\bigg(\frac{\pi k}{2n}\bigg) . $$